# How to disable default 'Click to edit' on Jeditable?

Tags: jeditable

I'm using the jeditable plugin for making some values editable. I noticed that when a value is empty the default text 'Click top edit' appears which I don't want. But I still want to make that field editable too. How to manage this?

I noticed a suggestion at http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5865/jeditable-and-default-click-to-edit/p1, but that does not seem to work - at least not for me; when using the placeholder : "" the field is not editable anymore.

My related code:

```
$('.edit').editable('edit_save.php', {
            cancel    : 'Cancel',
            submit    : 'OK'
});//$('.edit').editable('jeditable_save.php', {
```

Answer (score 4):

Without any text to fill it, the editable element needs to be an inline block with height and width like this:

`.edit {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 100px;
}`

and set a blank placeholder like you mentioned:

`$('.edit').editable(function (value, settings) {
        return value;
    }, {
        cssclass: 'editing',
        placeholder: '',
    });`

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdillon/37JqF/

Comment: placeholder; this is the parameter that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried add this row:  placeholder:'
>   &
>   nbsp;' and it works.

If you can add this row, you see your input is empty.

```
$('.edit').editable('Something', {

    something,...
    placeholder:'&nbsp;',

})
```